# data-target in submit button (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, submit

I would like the equivalent of something like this:

```
<button id="shownum" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popupnum">ok</button>
```

in rails submit like this

```
<%= f.submit ...... %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the syntax below for this:

```
<%= f.submit "Ok", id: "shownum", 'data-toggle': "modal", 'data-target': "#popupnum" %>
```

Attributes with a dash in them (like `data-toggle`) have to be in quotes.